# Auto Hotkey Asynchronous Loop

Tags: loops, asynchronous, autohotkey

**This is my code:**

```
toggle:=0

z::
    if GetKeyState("LButton") {
    toggle:= 0
        Send % "{Click Up}"
    Send % "{w Up}"
    Send % "{Ctrl Up}"
        BlockInput, MouseMoveOff
    } else {
        Send % "{Click Down}"
    Send % "{w Down}"
    Send % "{Ctrl Down}"
        BlockInput, MouseMove
    toggle := 1
    If (toggle := 1) 
            SetTimer, loop, -1 
        }
return

loop:
while (toogle := 1) {
    MouseMove, 50, 0, R
    MouseMove, -50, 0, R
    Sleep, 700 
}
return
```

It presses "left click", "w" and "ctrl"
If pressed "z" again it releases them

The loop should move the mouse every 1 second a bit the left and then the same amount back to the right

But it doesnt work

If i press "z" the loop doesnt stop

Comment: You do not get any key in your loop. Am I wrong?

Comment: the loop checks for the toogle variable and the toogle variable gets false if i press z again

Answer (score 0):

`:=` <sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetExpression.htm)</sup> is used to assign an expression's result, not to compare values.
Use the [`=` or `==`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#equal) operators to compare.
Or when you're simply checking true/false values,
`(toggle = 1)` is the same as `(toggle)` and
`(toggle = 0)` is the same as `(!toggle)`.

Also you misspelled `toggle` in your while loop.
Here's the the *fixed* code (it still seems quite broken logic wise).
But maybe you can now fix the logic when the script errors are gone.

```
z::
    if (GetKeyState("LButton"))
    {
        toggle := 0
        Send % "{Click Up}"
        Send % "{w Up}"
        Send % "{Ctrl Up}"
        BlockInput, MouseMoveOff
    } 
    else 
    {
        Send % "{Click Down}"
        Send % "{w Down}"
        Send % "{Ctrl Down}"
        BlockInput, MouseMove
        toggle := 1
        
        ;this check will never be false because literally right above you set the value?
        if (toggle) 
            SetTimer, loop, -1 
    }
return

loop:
    while (toggle) 
    {
        MouseMove, 50, 0, R
        MouseMove, -50, 0, R
        Sleep, 700 
    }
return
```

Comment: thanks, i check it later
i copied the loop from somewhere else, because im not familiar with ahk and didnt find anything better